# Why "console.log" doesn't work after a "return" command?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering why a `console.log` command, right after a return command, doesn't work.
Here's an example. Shouldn't the `console.log(square(50))` execute all the commands in the function body?

With this code, the console.log commands only displays the number 2500, but it doesn't display the phrase "This is the square of it". Why?

```js
function square(x) {
  return x * x;
  console.log(`This is the square of it`);
}

console.log(square(50));
```

Comment: Because it's unreachable - once you return, the execution of the function is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `return` make the function return immediately, any code written after is totally ignored.

`console.log` cannot bypass this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I just gotta write it before the return command then.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic programming knowledge, the explanation here will be kept "simple" for the target audience.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
> be returned to the function caller.

The purpose is the return is actually allowing the function to provide some form of information. When the return is reached, the code execution will typically go back to where the function was called from and evaluate to the return value, then continue execution from there:

```js
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

const result = sub(3, 2); // Returns 5
console.log(result); // Outputs 5.
console.log(sum(2, 2)); // Outputs 4
```

Additionally:

```js
function calculate(a, b, operation) {
   const addOperations = ["add", "sum", "plus"];
   const subtractOperations = ["take", "subtract", "minus"];
   const multiplyOperations = ["times", "multiply"];
   const divideOperations = ["divide", "divise"];
   if (addOperations.includes(operation.toLowerCase())) return a + b;
   if (subtractOperations.includes(operation.toLowerCase())) return a - b;
   if (multiplyOperations.includes(operation.toLowerCase())) return a * b;
   if (divideOperations.includes(operation.toLowerCase())) return a / b; 
}

console.log(calculate(3, 3, "multiply")); // Outputs 9
console.log(calculate(4, 4, "divide")); // Outputs 1
console.log(1, 1, ""); // Outputs undefined
```

If there is no return, it evaluates to undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Because **return** is a statement and any code written after return doesn't execute that's why `console.log` written after return statement doesn't execute. The output of above only will be **2500**

> `console.log` (`This is the square of it`); this line will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Because **return** ends the function , and the **console log** is ignored.

Instead of use 2 **console.log** you can use just 1 and call the function after , like this :

```
function square(x) {
let sq = x*x;
console.log(`This is the square of it: ${sq}`);
}
square(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statement ends the execution of function at that statement and no further lines will be executed as in your code.

So instead try this:

```js
function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}

console.log('This is the square of it: ', square(50));
```